# Converting a non-linear ODE to a Bernoulli equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's publicly available materials.  The first part of one of the recitation exercises runs as follows:  Show that
\begin{align}
(3e^{2y}x^{\frac{2}{3}} - x)y\prime = 1
\end{align}
becomes an equation of the Bernoulli type if $x$ and $y$ are interchanged.  Try as  I might, however, I can't see this.  Moreover, I've noticed that both the textbook (Birkhoff and Rota) and the study materials for this course are liberally strewn with typos, so maybe the question I'm trying to answer isn't the one I should be answering.

Here's what I know:  in general, a Bernoulli equation is of the form
\begin{align}
y\prime + p(x)y & = q(x)y^n
\end{align}
where $n\neq 1$.

If we swap $x$ and $y$ in the given equation, we obtain
\begin{align}
(3e^{2x}y^{\frac{2}{3}} - y)x\prime = 1\Rightarrow\\
\end{align}
Note that right away something seems off, as our ODE, which should ostensibly be of the form $x\prime + p(y)x = q(y)x^n$, is going to have that $3e^{2x}$ lurking around.  But of course there's a bigger problem  -- interchanging variables as we've done has nothing but a cosmetic effect on the situation.  That is, if the post-interchange equation can be manipulated into a Bernoulli equation, then so can the pre-interchange equation.

So assume that the question really means we should swap $x$ and $y$ but leave $y\prime$ intact.  Then the equation becomes
\begin{align}
(3e^{2x}y^{\frac{2}{3}} - y)y\prime & = 1
\end{align}
which seems a bit more promising. However, it's still not clear to me how to proceed.  We have
\begin{align}
y\prime & = \frac{1}{3e^{2x}y^{\frac{2}{3}} - y}\\
& = \frac{1}{y^{\frac{2}{3}}(3e^{2x} - y^{\frac{1}{3}})}
\end{align}
which is about as far as I can get.  Undoubtedly there's some algebraic manipulation I'm not seeing here which will get the equation into the form that I want -- assuming, of course, that the question is what I've taken it to be.  Any help -- either in solving the problem as presented or helping me see what it should be would be greatly appreciated.

(Here is a link to the problem in question, in case you'd like to take at the original -- it's #2 on the sheet:  http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-034-honors-differential-equations-spring-2009/recitations/MIT18_034s09_rec04_2_19.pdf)

Comment: Could it be that you should look at $x$ as a function of $y$? Then you get $$3e^{2y}x^{2/3}-x=x',$$ which, at least is closer to the Bernoulli equation, and can be solved...

Comment: @mickep:  This is lovely (and is indeed a Bernoulli equation), but I'm not sure how you got it.  I'm probably being dense...

Comment: @mickep:  Are you essentially assuming that the inverse function holds, and not interchanging anything at all?

Comment: That is how I read the "hint" in the sentence. In any case, you can always assume that it works, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm going with mickep's suggestion.  Assuming the function $y(x)$ is appropriately behaved (that is, that the inverse function theorem holds), we have
\begin{align}
y' & = \frac{1}{3e^{2y}x^{\frac{2}{3}} - x}\Rightarrow\\
\frac{dx}{dy} & = 3e^{2y}x^{\frac{2}{3}} - x\Rightarrow\\
\frac{dx}{dy} + x & = 3e^{2y}x^{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{align}
which is indeed a Bernoulli equation.